# ofstream writing extra zero bytes to file on Unix server

Tags: c++, file-io, xxd

Why does the following code write four bytes when run on my local Windows machine using Visual C++, yet writes 4 extra 0 bytes when I upload to my school's Unix server?

```
unsigned long temp = 1025;
ofstream file("test", ofstream::binary);
file.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(temp));
```

Here is the result using xxd locally: `0104 0000`

Here is the result on the Unix server: `0104 0000 0000 0000`

Is this a problem with what mode I am opening the file in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long` has implementation-defined size. Your Windows system uses a 32 bit (4 byte) `long` (even 64 bit Windows uses 32 bit `long`; otherwise it's rare to see on 64 bit OSes), while most if not all 64 bit UNIX-like systems I'm aware of have 64 bit (8 byte) `long`s. Since you're writing out `sizeof(temp)` bytes, and `temp` is `unsigned long`, you'll get different output sizes on different systems (you may also encounter byte order issues if you move from little endian to big endian machines).

If you need a consistent size, use the fixed width types from `<cstdint>`, e.g. `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: To be pedantic, the size of any data type in C++ is a feature of the C++ compiler, not the operating system. There is nothing preventing a compiler from providing 64-bit longs on Windows.

Comment: Worth noting that the C++ standard only has a hard specification for the minimum size of the fundamental integer types. The standard also guarantees that the size of a type will be no larger than the next integer type up. This means it is entirely possible (though unlikely) to have `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` all the same size, and at least 64 bit.

Comment: For further info, you'd want to compare and contrast [the ILP32 model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3024/lp64-1/index.html) (common to most 32 bit systems) with [the various 64 bit data models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Except ultimately, if you use any of the Windows API that's based on `long`s, you'll have serious problems if your compiler is using 64 bit `long`s, while WinAPI calls continue to expect 32 bit `long`s (unless the compiler is going to extra trouble to perform fixups, wrap WinAPI calls in a runtime adaptor layer, what have you). Yes, it's possible, but clearly the OP isn't in one of those weird cases, as evidenced by their program's behavior.

Comment: Well, that's why I said "to be pedantic"  :-)

Comment: @user4581301: Yup, that's why I was looking up the links to the various data models to make it clear how weird it can get. SILP64 is *strange* (I've worked on a Cray that behaved that way; sadly, I was porting code off it, and the original developers had been seriously lax in their data type choices because it didn't matter on the Crays).